# Integration of $\int\sin^{3}2x\, dx.$ using IBP

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am attempting to solve this integral:
$$\int\sin^{3}2x\, dx.$$

Using an identity, I have manipulated the integral into this:
$$\int\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos4x\right)\sin2x dx.$$

From here, using IBP, I let $u$ = $1-cos4x$ and $v'$ = sin2x

However, I obtained an answer of $\cos2x+\frac{1}{2}\cos2x\cos4x\ -\ \frac{1}{6}\cos6x$, which is nowhere near the intended answer in the solutions of $\frac{1}{6}\cos^{3}2x-\frac{1}{2}\cos2x$.

Any help on why my solution/method is incorrect will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the sine reduction formula, but let’s try it with your method.

First, $2x\mapsto u$ to get
$$u=2x,\quad\frac{du}{dx}=2,\quad dx=\frac{1}{2}du$$
$$\frac12\int\sin^3(u)du$$

Now, since $$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$
We have
$$\frac12\int\frac{\sin(u)-\sin(u)\cos(2u)}{2}du$$

Now, separate this into two integrals. The first one is trivial. For the second one, instead of parts, recall from product to sum formulas that $$\sin(A)\cos(B)=\frac{\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)}{2}$$

You should be able to take it from here :)

---

Rest of solution

> \begin{align*}
>  \frac12\int\frac{\sin(u)-\sin(u)\cos(2u)}{2}du&=\frac14\int\sin(u)du-\frac14\int\sin(u)\cos(2u)du\\
> &=-\frac14\cos(u)-\frac18\int \sin(3u)-\sin(u) du\\
> &=-\frac14\cos(2x)-\frac18\cos(2x)+\frac1{24}\cos(6x)\\
> &=\frac1{24}\cos(6x)-\frac38\cos(2x)
>  \end{align*}

As to convert this answer, I guess I'm somehow rusty on my trig manipulation skills because I was not able to but whatever. You'd probably have to use a bunch of product to sum or something but mathematica confirms they are equal so here.

[image]

---

Okay, so regarding parts, you technically *can* use it. I highly do not recommend doing so. A handy thing to keep in mind that whenever you have an integral that has sine and cosine multiplied with each other, you want to use product to sum, *not* parts.

I tried parts just then, and basically after 1 iteration, we have an integral with just sine and cosine. You can use the classic trick where we integrate by parts twice and subtract the integral (like in $\int e^x\sin(x)dx$) but this is like 3 integration by parts. My attempt took up half a page and I definetely will not be latexing it

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a couple of things to clarify please: I'm not sure, but I think you inadvertently made a typo by adding $\frac{1}{2}$ from the beginning. Also, does Integration by Parts not work at all in solving this integral, and if so, why?

Comment: @qwerty Ah that is supposed to be there! Let me add some clarrification

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks! Is it possible if you could please also clarify my latter question in my comment above :)

Comment: Alright, let me edit my answer this will take like  10 mins ish lol

Comment: @qwerty Ok uh i was originally going to add my parts attempt but it was way too extensive so I will just leave it as a description. Hopefulyl its clear enough :)

Comment: That's fine, your edit makes sense :) Just one more thing if that's ok with you please: How comes the answer you worked out does not equate with the given answer of $\frac{1}{6}\cos^{3}2x-\frac{1}{2}\cos2x$. ?

Comment: @qwerty we can use trig formulas to manipulate the answer into that form. Usually for trig integrals there are many different possible forms. There is a handy way to check if your antiderivative is right though. Let $$\int f(x)dx=F(x)$$ with this, we can verify such by numerically evaluating $$\int^{0.2}_{0.1}f(x)dx$$ and $F(0.2)-F(0.1)$ and see if they are equal (you can use some other bound too). Let me add to my answer tho hold on

Answer (score 3):

Integrate by parts as follows

\begin{align}
\int\sin^{3}2x\, dx
=&\ \frac16\int e^{-\frac32\tan^2 2x}d(e^{\frac32\tan^2 2x} \cos^3 2x )\\
=& \ \frac16 \cos^3 2x+ \int \sin 2x\ dx
=\frac16 \cos^3 2x-\frac12\cos 2x
\end{align}

Comment: @Quanto Thanks for your input! Could you perhaps please explain how the $e$ and $tan$ is involved with the integration by parts? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Normally, this integral does not need IBP as requested. But, it could done with some trial and search as shown.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As an alternative, I would recommend you the following identity
\begin{align*}
\sin(3\alpha) = 3\sin(\alpha) - 4\sin^{3}(\alpha)
\end{align*}

Based on it, the proposed integral reduces to
\begin{align*}
\int\sin^{3}(2x)\mathrm{d}x = \int\left[\frac{3\sin(2x) - \sin(6x)}{4}\right]\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Integration by parts is interesting as below:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
&I=\int \sin ^3 2 x d x=-\frac{1}{2} \int \sin ^2 2 x d(\cos 2 x)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \sin ^2 2 x \cos 2 x+\frac{1}{2} \int 4 \sin 2 x \cos ^2 2 xdx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \sin ^2 2 x \cos 2 x+2 \int \sin 2 x\left(1-\sin ^2 2 x\right) d x\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \sin ^2 2 x \cos 2 x+2 \int \sin 2 x d x-2 I\\
I&=-\frac{\cos 2 x}{6}\left(\sin ^2 2 x+2\right)+C \\(\textrm{  OR}&  =\frac16 \cos^3 2x-\frac12\cos 2x+C)
\end{aligned}
$$